# Pythonic way of handling string formatted loop

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have the following code, and the idea is to be able to iterate over `root` for each string in `some_list[j]`. The goal is to stay away from nested for loops and learn a more pythonic way of doing this. I would like to return  each `value` for the first item in `some_list` then repeat for the next item in `some_list`.

```
for i, value in enumerate(root.iter('{0}'.format(some_list[j])))
        return value
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: root is

```
tree = ElementTree.parse(self._file)
root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: While it's great to aim for a pythonic way of doing things, make sure you understand what the `return` statement does first. What do you want to do with these values?

Comment: Loops aren't inherently bad. Why don't you first write it out as a nested loop, to make it clearer what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: @rogaos yes I understand what return does, maybe I should use `yield`? I would like to push them to another function for further processing.

Comment: @user1991424 without any conditions, you might as well not have a loop and always return the first value then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're trying to do is this:

```
values = ('{0}'.format(root.iter(item)) for item in some_list)
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    # ...
```

But really, `'{0}'.format(foo)` is silly; it's just going to do the same thing as `str(foo)` but more slowly and harder to understand. Most likely you already have strings, so all you really need is:

```
values = (root.iter(item) for item in some_list)
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    # ...
```

You could merge those into a single line, or replace the genexpr with `map(root.iter, some_list)`, etc., but that's the basic idea.

---

At any rate, there are no nested loops here. There are two loops, but they're just interleaving—you're still only running the inner code once for each item in `some_list`.

Answer (score 0):

So, given List A, which contains multiple lists, you want to return the first element of each list? I may not be understanding you correctly, but if so you can use a list comprehension...very "Pythonic" ;)

```
    In [1]: some_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

    In [2]: new = [x[0] for x in some_list]

    In [3]: new
    Out[3]: [1, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`chain()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)
 from the `itertools` module. It would look something like

```
from itertools import chain

all_items = chain(*[root.iter('{0}'.format(x) for x in some_list)])
for i, value in enumerate(all_items):
    return value # or yield i, value, or whatever you need to do with value
```